# stratify data without train_test_split shuffle

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification, xgboost

I'm trying to do binary_classification on stock market data.

Since it is a timeseries data, I don't want to shuffle the data.

I would stratify the data without shuffling my data.

sklearn train_test_split stratify works only when the setting is shuffle=True.

[See [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html): `If shuffle=False then stratify must be None.`]

Is there any alternative?

Note: My model utilises xgboost algorithm.

Also Note: I don't want to use train_test_split function. I already did that manually like this.

```
train_df = df.iloc[0: math.floor(9 * len(df)/10)]
test_df = df.iloc[math.floor(9 * len(df)/10):]
```

Comment: What are the classes you are trying to stratify?

Comment: @rickhg12hs `0` and `1` since it is a binary classification.

Comment: Could you use a "running window" with your time series where you search for the proper stratification for your train and test sample?  I.e., somewhere in the first 70% of the samples, the 0/1 ratio is pretty close, and then somewhere in the remaining 30% somewhere is pretty close for the test strata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using StratifiedKFold?
You can give hyperparameter `shuffe =Flase`
It will generate indices of train and test data in number of folds

Here is the documentation link

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html?highlight=stratified#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold

This may help

Comment: I haven't tried `StratifiedKFold`. But will give it a try.